# Can shifting the centre of gravity of a ball move it, no matter the weight?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

Just a thought, but could you have a car but the wheels are balls, then the car goes forward when you shift the centre of gravity of the balls to towards the front of the car, making them roll forward and with them the car and you, no matter the weight of the car. If so, you could power a car with 9v (powering the servos shifting a weight in the balls that shifts their centre of gravity)! Please say if I am right/wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could probably make an arrangement like that work if you were careful to minimise energy lost due to friction and inelastic collisions - but $9$V servos are never going to move large weights quickly, so the top speed of the car will be very low.

Comment: Thanks but if you did use 9v servos would it work (would it move albeit slowly)

Comment: @STEMguy24 That's more an engineering question than a physics question. It would depend on many factors.